# объединить 3 запроса UPDATE MySQL

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток!

Нужно объединить 3 запроса UPDATE но они с подвохом... дело в том что мне надо обновить данные у 2х пользователей в одной таблице по их id...

```sql
UPDATE posts, users_statistic 
/* Тут нужно увеличить просмотр на 1... тут все ок */
SET posts.views = posts.views + 1, 
/* Тут нужно увеличить просмотр у автора поста пусть будет id = 10 */
users_statistic.views = users_statistic.views + 1, 
/* Тут нужно увеличить просмотр у того кто смотрит пост пусть будет id = 15 */
users_statistic.your_views = users_statistic.your_views + 1
WHERE posts.id = 1 AND 
/* Как тут указать что для одной строки нужно увеличение у автора а в другом у того кто смотрит */
```

Вот 3 отдельных запроса:

```sql
UPDATE posts SET views = views + 1 WHERE id=?;
UPDATE users_statistic SET views = views + 1 WHERE id=?;
UPDATE users_statistic SET your_views = your_views + 1 WHERE id=?;
```

- в первом передается id поста
- во втором id автора
- в третьем id того кто просматривал

Таблица выглядит таким образом :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!